# PyG: Remove existing edges from prediction matrix

Tags: python, pytorch, recommendation-engine, pytorch-geometric

I'm currently working on a recommender system using PyG.
The edges are defined as follows:

```
edge_index = tensor([[   0,    0,    0,  ..., 9315, 9317, 9317],
         [ 100,  448,  452,  ...,  452,    1,  307]], device='cuda:0')}
```

`edge_index[0]` containing the indexes for a student and `edge_index[1]` containing the index of connected modules (both have the same length). Therefore `edge_index[0][i]` is the source node of edge `i` and `edge_index[1][i]` is the destination of edge `i`.

After model training, I'm generating a 2D-tensor `recs` with the shape of # of Students x # of Modules, with values from 0-1. 0 = not recommended and 1 = recommended.  `recs` could look like this:

```
recs = tensor([0.54, 0.23, 0.98, ..., 0.12, 0.43, 0.87],
              ...,
              [0.43, 0.53, 0.12, ..., 0.92, 0.12, 0.53])
```

Of course, I don't want to recommend a module if the student has already taken it. Is there a way to set all edges from the original graph to zero, by using the `edge_index` from PyG as coordinates or something?

Basically i want to set specific values in `recs` to 0 like this:

```
for i in range(0, len(edge_index[0])):
  recs[edge_index[0][i]][edge_index[1][i]] = 0
```

Is there a way using the tensor functions to achieve this?

Comment: Please provide a minimal example **including** `edge_index`

Comment: `edge_index` is equal to `('student', 'has_taken', 'module')`

Comment: You are not answering the question. You haven't provided a minimal example nor shown how `edge_index` is shaped.

Comment: I changed the question accordingly.

Comment: *"Is there a way to set all edges from the original graph to zero, by using the edge_index from PyG as coordinates or something?"* can you provide a clear an minimal example including a smaller version of your model output (the one supposed to contain the values).

Comment: I hope the question is understandable now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you want to index `recs` on both axes simultaneously a straight implementation is to to vectorize your for loop as:

```
>>> recs[edge_index[0], edge_index[1]] = 0
```

Which you can improve by splitting `edge_index` with *`tuple`*:

```
>>> recs[tuple(edge_index)] = 0
```